# Инициализация списка как аргумент по умолчанию

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def add(mass=[]):
    mass.append(1)
    return mass


add()
print(add())

>>> [1, 1]
```

Почему это работает именно так?
Где хранится список и почему он не обнуляется?

Comment: Аргумент по умолчанию создаётся один раз. Поэтому, если в качестве аргумента по умолчанию выбрать изменяемый тип данных (словарь или список), то он будет общим у всех вызовов функции. Соответственно, если вы один раз вызовете функцию с аргументом по умолчанию и внутри неё в этот аргумент добавите элементы, то они будут там и при следующем вызове этой функции.

Поэтому рекомендуется никогда не использовать в качестве аргумента по умолчанию объект изменяемого типа, чтобы случайно не напороться на такое поведение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аргумент по умолчанию создается только один раз при запуске программы и при каждом вызове функции мы ссылаемся на один и тот же участок в памяти.

https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/ispolzovanie-spiskov-list-python/neozhidannoe-povedenie-spiskov/

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае при определении функции определяется переменная
mass = []

в дальнейшем когда ты вызываешь метод без параметров, то ты все свои операции производишь над этой переменной

Если ты хочешь, что бы она обнулялась всегда, когда ты вызываешь метод без параметров, то лучше сделать так:

```
def add(mass=None):
    if mass is None:
        mass = []
    mass.append(1)
    return mass
```

подробней можешь почитать поискав по `python mutable default argument`